# Why undefined class and/or applet with an Eclipse setup?

Tags: java, eclipse, processing

I am trying to setup a Java project based on the Processing library and my own classes. While I could get a simple project running, I have troubles to get a project running with Processing (core.jar) and my custom classes.

My current setup is as in the screenshot:

```
 src
    |--- default.package
    |   L--- sketch.java
    |--- matrix
    |   L--- custom.java, ...
```

[image: project properties]

Comment: You need the `processing-core.jar`

Comment: I deleted the project, re-did exactly the steps as described here: http://processing.org/tutorials/eclipse/ - but again, the debugger does not have access to my custom class.

Comment: Which errormessage shows eclipse?

Comment: The source of `ClassnotFouundException` is not found. That means that your custom class is not found!!

Comment: hmm.. so, the root cause is the build path? the package setup? It's been a while that I used eclipse, sorry

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54985/discussion-between-jens-and-poseid).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You are following a wrong package structure. Remove that matrix folder and create the package matrix in src.
- Now include processing-core.jar
- Then do a clean built and it should work.

It may ask for other dependant jars. Whenever a new project is created its advisable to use maven because a single dependency entry will include all dependant jar files required.

Comment: I follow the same process as in http://processing.org/tutorials/eclipse/ - I created a new project, adjusted the package, but now, the debugger still complains, see screenshot

Comment: Press that button(Edit Source Lookup Path) -> Click Default and press OK

Comment: Again: source not found.

Comment: Are you able to browse and select the project in that popup(The popup which you get when you press "Edit Source Lookup Path")

Comment: the popup is as in the screenshot above

Comment: Yes..select that Java project matrix(The folder with a 'J' icon). Press OK and see.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54986/discussion-between-poseid-and-dinal).

Comment: Hope you have configured your server in eclipse using "Add server wizard"

Comment: I am in office now. Chat is disabled in office network